# Laravel relations where the relation brings the correct users data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

So I tried setting up somewhat of an inhouse sports page for my forum users where they basically can enter who they think will win the game and then after the result has come in they will be awarded points if they were correct.

While doing this I ran into an issue. So far I have the games in the database and then I created an Results relation.
The problem is that when the user is viewing all the games on a said date (Several events) then the relation doesn't know which one belongs to said user. I tried for a couple of hours now but I am honestly drawing a blank. Take a look at this:

Route:

```
Route::get('/event/{date}/list', 'Other\OtherController@indexDateGames');
```

Controller:

```
public function indexDateGames($date)
{
    $dateToday = (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $events = Event::where('date', $date)->get();
    $uid = Auth::user()->id;


    $vars['uid'] = $uid;
    $vars['date'] = $date;
    $vars['dateToday'] = $dateToday;
    $vars['events'] = $events;

    if ($date >= $dateToday) {
        $vars['url'] = 'eventsUpcoming';
    } else {
        $vars['url'] = 'eventsPassed';
    }

    return view('other.event_on_date', $vars);
}
```

Model Result :

```
    public function event()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
}
```

Model Event :

```
        public function result()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Result::class);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div id="spinner" style="margin-top:200px;margin-left:47%;">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="data" style="display:none;margin:10px;">
            <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tid</th>
                    <th>Resultat</th>
                    <th>Ditt val</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tid</th>
                    <th>Resultat</th>
                    <th>Ditt val</th>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($events as $event)

                        @if ('2017-09-16 16:00:00' < $event->start)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$event->start->format('H:i')}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        @if (isset($event->result->result))
                                            @if ($event->result->result == 1)
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">{{$event->home}}</a>
                                                <a href="{{ URL::to('/event/' . $event->id . '/changeresult/2/' . $uid) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">X</a>
                                                <a href="{{ URL::to('/event/' . $event->id . '/changeresult/3/' . $uid) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">{{$event->away}}</a>
                                            @elseif ($event->result->result == 2)
                                                <a href="{{ URL::to('/event/' . $event->id . '/changeresult/1/' . $uid) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">{{$event->home}}</a>
                                                <a href="{{ URL::to('#') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">X</a>
                                                <a href="{{ URL::to('/event/' . $event->id . '/changeresult/3/' . $uid) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">{{$event->away}}</a>
                                            @elseif ($event->result->result == 3)
                                                <a href="{{ URL::to('/event/' . $event->id . '/changeresult/1/' . $uid) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">{{$event->home}}</a>
                                                <a href="{{ URL::to('/event/' . $event->id . '/changeresult/2/' . $uid) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">X</a>
                                                <a href="{{ URL::to('#') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">{{$event->away}}</a>
                                            @endif
                                        @else
                                            <a href="{{ URL::to('/event/' . $event->id . '/result/1/' . $uid) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">{{$event->home}}</a>
                                            <a href="{{ URL::to('/event/' . $event->id . '/result/2/' . $uid) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">X</a>
                                            <a href="{{ URL::to('/event/' . $event->id . '/result/3/' . $uid) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">{{$event->away}}</a>
                                        @endif
                                    </td>

                        @elseif (isset($event->final_result))
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$event->start->format('H:i')}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    @if ($event->final_result == 1)
                                        <a href="{{ URL::to('#') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">{{$event->home}} vann matchen över {{$event->away}}</a>
                                    @elseif ($event->final_result == 2)
                                        <a href="{{ URL::to('#') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Matchen slutade lika mellan {{$event->home}} och {{$event->away}}</a>
                                    @elseif ($event->final_result == 3)
                                        <a href="{{ URL::to('#') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">{{$event->away}} vann matchen över {{$event->home}}</a>
                                    @endif
                                </td>

                        @else
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$event->start->format('H:i')}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{ URL::to('#') }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Matchen låst - Resultat ej fastställt</a>
                                </td>

                        @endif
                        @if (isset($event->result->result))
                            <td>
                                @if ($event->result->result == 1)
                                    <a href="{{ URL::to('#') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">{{$event->home}}</a>
                                @elseif ($event->result->result == 2)
                                    <a href="{{ URL::to('#') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Lika</a>
                                @elseif ($event->result->result == 3)
                                    <a href="{{ URL::to('#') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">{{$event->away}}</a>
                                @endif
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @else
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{ URL::to('#' . $event->id . '/result/1') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Inget val gjort</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endif


                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anybody know how to make it so that the relation basically knows that
"$event->result" Is actually YOUR result? I know this doesnt work, but this is just an example:

```
$event->result(WhereUserId($uid)->result
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/UtFEFPc.png
This is what the view looks like.

Comment: What is the rerlationship between user and event ?

Comment: Basically no relation at all between them. There are 50 users that all have access to the same events. It´s the results that are unique by user. Not sure if that made sense. The event is just a way of showing when there is a game right now, and then you create your result based on what games there are.

Comment: And every event has one result ?

Comment: Every event has one result per user as it sits now, I know the model is crapped there but I am unsure on how to use hasMany and make sure that it only finds the result that belongs to you in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the event should have many results

```
public function results()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Result::class);
}
```

For the query :

```
$events = Event::with(['results' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
                }])
                ->where('date', $date)
                ->get();
```

Comment: Added "" on the =, seems to run now. Need to test it but looks solid so far. Thanks. :)